# Is it possible to style a permanently animated button/link using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Usually they get animated when hovering over or clicking them but I want a button that stays animated all the time to draw the attention. For example a gradient runs through it every couple of seconds or it changes its colour slightly.

I guess it can only be done using CSS + JS, not CSS alone?

fiy. It's a PHP/HTML website

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/30yrL4pe/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css animations `-webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite;` . So you can loop animation or end up your transition to stay where it has been ended `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. Please read up here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/